# How long until a job that has finished executing gets removed from dba_jobs?

Tags: oracle, dbms-job

If I submit a job via dbms_job.submit and I commit then it runs until completion. How much longer will it be available for me to view on the dba_jobs view and what determines this time?

Comment: think it will be there till your schema exists. Furthermore, you should consider using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` over `DBMS_JOB`, which has become deprecated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kaushik said, the `DBMS_JOB` package has been superseeded by the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package [source](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS019). 
They have job names instead of numbers, a proper time scheduler language, and many views to monitor execution etc.

The `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` procedure has even a dedicated parameter for your question called `auto_drop`:

> This flag if `TRUE`, causes the job to be automatically dropped after it has been completed. [source](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300)

But you asked for `DBMS_JOB`, and I am rather sure that the job is not deleted. I just verified that it is removed when the user/schema is dropped.

As admin:

```
CREATE USER a IDENTIFIED BY a;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE JOB TO a;
```

As user a:

```
DECLARE
  my_job number;
BEGIN
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(job => my_job, 
    what => 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(NULL); END;',
    next_date=>sysdate+(1/24/60),
    interval=>'sysdate+(1/24/60)');
  COMMIT;
end;
/
```

As admin:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_JOBS WHERE schema_user='A';
JOB LOG_USER LAST_DATE           NEXT_DATE ...
25  A        29.06.2018 13:46:25 29.06.2018 13:47:25

DROP USER A;
User A dropped.

SELECT * FROM DBA_JOBS WHERE schema_user='A';
no rows returned
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source for your verification?